# Bishul Akum with Electricity

Tags: halacha, electricity, bishul-akum

Someone mentioned to me that the opinion of Rav Benzion Abba Shaul ZTL was that there is no Bishul Akum with regards to any form of electric cooking such as ovens. Can anyone confirm if this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exact view is cited [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/halakha/yoreh-deah/kashrut-and-issur-veheter/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9D) in his name. The reason given is that the action of "lighting" such an oven only sends a short pulse to activate the electric heat, but the electricity which causes the heat afterwards is not directly caused by the non-Jew.

> באשר לבישול על ידי חשמל - הרב בן ציון אבא שאול (הובאה דעתו בשו"ת עטרת פז, ב', קד) כתב שפעולת ההדלקה יוצרת רק את הכח החשמלי הראשון, שאין בו כדי לבשל, ואילו החשמל הזורם אחר כך כבר אינו מכוחו של הנוכרי אלא כוח כוחו, ולכן אין בבישול בחשמל איסור של בישול עכו"ם.